# What is the best way to retrieve a list of all core and custom entry points?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I work quite a bit with custom entry points in SugarCRM and SuiteCRM. I was wondering if there is a quick way to list every entrypoint and the file associated with it?

Comment: Did my answer to your other post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43489844/where-do-you-place-your-custom-entry-point-definitions/43496544#43496544) noting the location of the directories answer this sufficiently?

Comment: Starting from SugarCRM 7.7 http://site_url/rest/v10/help is the right way to get details about all that. http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/Integration/Web_Services/v10/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Entry points can be defined in so many places, the key here will be to find all of the definition files and then `cat` each one of them to find what they're doing.

**Possible Entry Point Locations**

- custom Extension-Framework, application-wide entry points:

  - `$ ls -1d custom/Extension/application/Ext/EntryPointRegistry`
- custom Extension-Framework, module-specific entry points:

  - `$ ls -1d custom/Extension/modules/*/Ext/EntryPointRegistry`
- custom non-ext-framework (legacy), application-wide entry points

  - `$ ls custom/include/MVC/Controller/entry_point_registry.php`
- custom non-ext-framework (legacy) module-specific entry points are housed in custom/modules...

  - `$ ls custom/modules/*/entry_point_registry.php`
- These can be in the root level module dir as well. I don't think any out of the box modules ever did this, but you could do it with a custom module

  - `$ ls modules/*/entry_point_registry.php`
- Out-of-the-box application wide entry points...

  - `include/MVC/Controller/entry_point_registry.php`